What processes would a biological creature's body require in order to be an electromagnet?
Within the setting I'm creating, there is a species of bipedal aliens that live in a world of metallic trees. The basics of the idea was a desert of resources, not sand, where most of the planet's flora are enormous weeds that contain most of the surface's metals. These weeds have produced a bark that's mostly metal and therefore magnetic, and humanoid creatures have evolved to walk on the sides of the trees using magnetic forces.
As of right now, I've planning on these bipedal aliens to have iron skeletons. I've considered steel skeletons in the past (and I'm still working on what biological processes it would take for a creature to produce steel organically) but for now iron seems to be the better choice. This skeleton would be the coil required for them to produce electromagnetic forces, as they push electricity through their body. This would be channeled down to their hooves, which act as the contact point with the metal trees. If anyone has thoughts on how this would be structured, I would appreciate it, but that's not the purpose of my question.
My real question is what biological processes are needed to turn this skeleton into an electromagnet. Most of the electric biology I've looked at so far (such as electric eels) don't last longer than a few moments. At the same time, these creatures couldn't produce constant magnetic force, or they'd be rooted to wherever they stood. Thus the idea for an electromagnet (which can be turned off) rather than just a set of lodestones for hooves.
